# Sharing sessions between webapps in Jetty 8

Tags: jetty, jetty-8

I am looking into migrating from Tomcat to Jetty 8 for a custom web application that will essentially be a portal (though it won't be using a JSR-168 or similar portal container).  The key concept for the purposes of this post is that the user will only need to log in once, and then he will need to access URLs from several different web applications all running on the same Jetty server.  Once the user has logged in they should automatically be authenticated to any other web application running on the server.

Tomcat has the org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn valve which accomplishes this exact task.  Once you log into a web application, the SingleSignOn valve will automatically log you into any other web applications.

So, is there a similar way to provide this same functionality in Jetty 8?  It seems that there is a separate SessionManager for each web application.  Can you configure or programatically assign the same SessionManager instance to each web application?  Is there some other solution that is provided by Jetty out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

HashSSORealm provides a simple way to use SingleSign on with Jetty. See:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Single+Sign+On+-+Jetty+HashSSORealm

Comment: HashSSORealm is removed in jetty 7,8 and 9 if I'm not mistaken